# Discord JS edit embed message "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot post a message embed and I want to edit a "field" name to add "message.id". I need to do it after posting because I can't have the ID before. I don't know why it doesn't work (msg.id is fine) ?

```
                  message.channel.send({ embed: embedMessageData }).then((msg) => {

                    msg.embeds[0].fields[4].name = 'message ID :' + msg.id;

                    msg.edit(new Discord.MessageEmbed(msg.embeds[0].fields[4]));
```

Comment: Are there five fields in the embed?

Comment: Yes, when I post the embed message I make a last field and I want to edit them.